# Google Sheet | Extract multiple values from one string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract all the strings end with "KT" and put them into one cell, however it only show the first result (24010KT)
Preferred result: 24010KT,VRB05KT,21008KT,26008KT,VRB04KT

I used below formula,
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\w+KT")

String in A1
//
TAF 110500Z 1106/1212 24010KT 9999 FEW010 SCT030 TX33/1106Z
TX32/1206Z TN28/1122Z TEMPO 1106/1112 4000 SHRA FEW010CB SCT020 TEMPO GR
1109/1115 VRB05KT TEMPO 1120/1202 4000 SHRA FEW010CB SCT020=  SS
METAR 110630Z 21008KT 190V250 9999 FEW018 32/24 Q1007 NOSIG=
METAR 110530Z 26008KT 240V300 9999 2800N SHRA FEW018 31/26 Q1008
NOSIG=   SS
METAR 110430Z VRB04KT 9999 FEW018 SCT028 32/25 Q1008 NOSIG=
//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=join(", ", filter(split(A1, " "), regexmatch(split(A1, " "), ".*KT|MPS")))
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thanks a lot.
But if I also want to extract "*MPS" OR "*KT", how should I amend the formula?

Comment: Glad to hear that worked. Since you are new here, you may want to check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I updated the formula so that it should work for strings ending with 'MPS' or 'KT'. Hope that helps?

Comment: Thank you. That's really help!!